# Login Route after firebase authentication googlesignin vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I have this method for Social Login, But after login my router not replacing to home. Not sure whats wrong.

```
socialloginGoogle() {                   
                    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
                    firebase
                    .auth()
                    .signInWithPopup(provider)
                    .then(() => {                        
                        router.push('home')
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                            this.error = err.message;
                        });
                }
```